# Javascript AJAX optimize speed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

**Can someone Identify wether this is good practice or needs improvement**

```
document.querySelector('#search-input').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
        var query = event.target.value;
        //console.log(query);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/admin-tasks/search?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var tasks = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //console.log(tasks);

                // Hide all rows
                var allRows = document.querySelectorAll('.task-row');
                allRows.forEach(function(row) {
                    row.style.display = 'none';
                });

                // Show only rows that match fetched data
                tasks.forEach(function(task, index) {
                var taskRow = document.querySelectorAll('.task-row')[index];
                    if (taskRow) {
                        console.log(task.faculty_image)
                        taskRow.style.display = '';
                        taskRow.querySelector('.task-name-text').textContent = task.task_name;
                        taskRow.querySelector('.faculty-name img').src = task.faculty_image;
                        taskRow.querySelector('.faculty-name-text').textContent = task.faculty_name;

                        var dateCreatedElements = taskRow.querySelectorAll('.date-created');
                        dateCreatedElements[0].innerHTML = task.date_created_formatted + "<br>" + task.date_created_time;

                        var dueDateElements = taskRow.querySelectorAll('.due-date');
                        dueDateElements[0].innerHTML = task.due_date_formatted + "<br>" + task.due_date_time;

                        // Check if the due date is in the past and add text-danger
                        if (task.due_date_past) {
                            dueDateElements[0].classList.add('text-danger');
                        }
                        else {
                            dueDateElements[0].classList.remove('text-danger');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
```

I tried the developer tool and here what i got in performance, im not sure what this tells wether good enough or not

```
5 ms  Loading
62 ms  Scripting
128 ms  Rendering
66 ms  Painting
129 ms  System
4788 ms  Idle
5178 ms  Total
```

Answer (score 1):

**Comments**

Some ways that code can be improved by are:

1. Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of regular functions. They use less resources.
2. Avoid querying multiple times for the same thing. Do it once and assign it to a constant variable.
3. Avoid using shorthand functions like `forEach` or `map` and instead opt for using [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) or [while-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while). They do the same thing but are much faster. See [Loop Optimization](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-optimize-your-javascript-apps-using-loops-d5eade9ba89f/) and [Performance Benchmarks](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/)
4. Utilize [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). It makes code easy to read/debug and you avoid the multiple levels of thenable hell.
5. An improvement that can be done is to create a [html template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) row and to clone that template content for each new row that needs to be created.

**JS**

```js
const searchHandler = async ( { target=null }={} ) => {
    if ( target == null || !target.value ) return;

    try {
        const query = `/admin-tasks/search?query=${encodeURIComponent( target.value )}`;
        const result = await fetch( query ).then( response => response.text() ) ?? '';

        const tasks = JSON.parse( result );
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.task-row');

        for ( const row of rows || [] ){
            row.setAttribute('hidden','');
        }

        for ( let i=0, il=tasks.length; i<il; i++ ){
            const row = rows[i];
            const task = tasks[i];

            if ( !row ) continue;

            row.removeAttribute('hidden');
            row.querySelector('.task-name-text').textContent = task.task_name;
            row.querySelector('.faculty-name img').src = task.faculty_image;
            row.querySelector('.faculty-name-text').textContent = task.faculty_name;
            row.querySelector('.date-created').innerHTML = `${task.date_created_formatted}<br>${task.date_created_time}`;

            const dueDateElement = row.querySelector('.due-date');
            dueDateElement.innerHTML = `${task.due_date_formatted}<br>${task.due_date_time}`;

            if ( task.due_date_past ) dueDateElement.classList.add('text-danger');
            else dueDateElement.classList.remove('text-danger');
        }
    } catch( error ) {
        console.error( error );
    }
}
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input');
searchInput.addEventListener( 'input', searchHandler );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could win some in speed if you prepared your html into a string and then outputted it all at once to the DOM, if possible. Several small DOM changes will often take more time than one big one (since the browser has to recalculate the DOM for each change).

I do understand that you want to set different event handlers, but you could use **delegated events** for that:

https://javascript.info/event-delegation

*On a slightly off-topic note:* Consider stop using **XMLHttpRequest** for AJAX and replace with **fetch**. It's not going to speed of your code, but is much easier to work with:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Can you show me the refractored code of prepared html into a string then outputting it, I tried it but it overwrites the initial table data